# Why does the memory address change every time I run the same print statement?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I am getting a different memory location in my C program every time I run the exact same statement. Shouldn't this never change? And yes it still happens if I change &p to &x. I realize those two should be different but this happens when I repeatedly run (NOT COMPILE) the program to view it's memory address.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
  int x = 30;
  int* p;
  p = &x;
  
  printf("%p \n", &p);
}
```

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIV9F.png)

Comment: Why do you think that it *should never change*?

Comment: Fyi, given that `printf` argument list, both the `int x` declaration and `p = ` statement are pointless; you're printing the address of the pointer variable `p`, not the address held *within* the pointer variable `p`. And you really should include the repetitious sample output you claim you're getting.

Comment: @alex01011 I was taught that the memory address you designate for a variable would never change. How else can the computer use a pointer?

Comment: whozcraig, Yes I'm doing that intenionally to check to see if the address held for p as a pointer changes. It does. Also you have to click proof to see the image I included of the repitition.

Comment: 011c Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the memory address change every time I run

Because your system uses [address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (ASLR), and in particular randomizes stack placement.

On Linux, you could disable ASLR for a single process like so:

```
setarch -R ./a.out
```

Running the program under GDB also disables ASLR by default.

> I was taught that the memory address you designate for a variable would never change.

The address of a stack variable will in fact never change *during a particular execution of your program*. It can only change between different runs.

Comment: Thank you Russian, that is the answer I was looking for.